# Separate the title from the tabPanels in navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to put all `tabPanel`s in a row below the title of a `navbarPage`? In other words, I would like to keep the appearance of the `navbarPage` but on two rows: the title on the first one, and the `tabPanel`s on the second. This would allow to "isolate" the title by keeping it on a single row.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "some title",
  tabPanel("first tab"),
  tabPanel("second tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that this doesn't have to be a `navbarPage`. Any `UI` that could do that is accepted but it has to have the appearance of a `navbarPage` (no space between the rows, etc.). Hope this is clear enough.

Also asked [on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/separate-the-title-from-the-tabpanels-in-navbarpage/59355)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the title to have 100% width via CSS, thereby moving the `tabPanel`s below it:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "some title",
  tabPanel("first tab"),
  tabPanel("second tab"),
  tags$style(HTML(".navbar-header { width:100% }
                   .navbar-brand { width: 100%; text-align: center }")) # center text
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks, additionally, do you know how to center the title?

Comment: Yes, you would need to also make the `navbar-brand` span full width, and have text be center-aligned. I edited my answer.